# Iphone simulator 4.0 home button does not stop xcode debugger

Tags: iphone

Can any one help me ?

I run my application via xcode iphone simulator 4.0 , now i want to stop my application ,so when i click my iphone simulator home button it didnt stop the debugger . I dont know why ?

Can anyone help me ?

The xcode debugger is still running ?
I didnt see such a problem in iphone os 3.0...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As said below it is suspended. You can also "Stop" it in the debugger rather than the sim/home double tap + remove. The debugger is still active during suspension, so if you restart, you can still hit breakpoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The home button now suspends the application in the background.  With iOS 4 you must kill the process.

Comment: @dragon: You can kill the process by: double tapping the home button, then you should see your app in the toolbar, hold your finger down over it and then press the '-' button to kill the process.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there a option for terminating app in the xcode itself? I suppose there is red button that can stop the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can force your application not to suspend but actually killing itself by adding "Application does not run in background" in your -Info.plist file.